# Conversation always ending after the welcome message from the action

Tags: actions-on-google

I’m using the Node.js client library to write my action, but the microphone gets closed after the first message and I never get the answer from the user.
This is the code I’m using:

```
let intent = assistant.getIntent();
switch (intent) {
  case WELCOME_INTENT:
    assistant.tell(‘Hi! Tell me something and I’ll repeat it.');
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `assistant.ask()` when you expect a response from the user. The `assistant.tell()` method speaks back the text to the user and ends the conversation by closing the microphone.

More details at https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/sdk/dialogs-and-fulfillment.